# How to draw existing <img> to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know I can do this using javascript:

```
var ctx = getCanvas('testCanvas').getContext('2d'); // get Canvas context
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'test.png';
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 200, 200); // x, y, width, height
}
```

But how to draw existing  tag to canvas:

In html:

```
<img src='test.png'>
```

Why I want to do this? I want to optimize image loading using pagespeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very first google hit for your question is promising:

```
var c=document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("existingHTMLImageElementId");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

See [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("test");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("imgID");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your  has the id `#image`, you could use

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");
var ctx = getCanvas('testCanvas').getContext('2d'); // get Canvas context
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 200, 200); // x, y, width, height
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if img.onload will be called?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an `<img>` tag with id of image. You can obtain the image reference by using the getElementById method. Something like the following:

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");
```

Then using your code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the image src to your new image

```
var ctx = getCanvas('testCanvas').getContext('2d'); // get Canvas context
var img = new Image();
img.src = document.getElementById('testImage').src;
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 200, 200); // x, y, width, height
}
```

add id to your image element

```
<img src='test.png' id="testImage">
```

Comment: will this cause request the image twice?

Comment: No..Image will be access only once